# react-native: How to add header animation in ScrollView onScroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-animations

I am implementing animated header with ScrollView on screen. on scrollView onScroll I am also setting myview on base of scrollview Y position.
Like this

```
const onScroll = ({ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y, x } } }) => {
    let _currentSection;
    // loop sections to calculate which section scrollview is on
    state.sections.forEach((section, index) => {
      // adding 15 to calculate Text's height
      const moveToPOsition = wp('24') * 5.8 * index

      console.log((y), state[section], index, moveToPOsition)
      if ((y + 15) > moveToPOsition) _currentSection = index
    })
    // settint the currentSection to the calculated current section
    setState((currentState) => ({ ...currentState, currentSection: _currentSection }))
}
```

Now on implementing animated header I need to add animation code onScroll.
This one

```
const handleScroll = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: { y: scrollY.current },
        },
      },
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: true,
    },
  );
```

When I add both codes togather and called onScoll of scrollview they does not work ... while separately they work.

```
const onScroll = ({ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y, x } } }) => {
    let _currentSection;
    // loop sections to calculate which section scrollview is on
    state.sections.forEach((section, index) => {
      // adding 15 to calculate Text's height
      const moveToPOsition = wp('24') * 5.8 * index

      console.log((y), state[section], index, moveToPOsition)
      if ((y + 15) > moveToPOsition) _currentSection = index
    })
    // settint the currentSection to the calculated current section
    setState((currentState) => ({ ...currentState, currentSection: _currentSection }))


    Animated.event(
      [
        {
          nativeEvent: {
            contentOffset: { y: scrollY.current },
          },
        },
      ],
      {
        useNativeDriver: true,
      },
    )

  }
```

Calling onScoll like this

```
<Animated.ScrollView
   style={styles.scrollView}
   ref={scrollView}
   contentContainerStyle={{paddingTop: headerHeight}}
   scrollEventThrottle={100}
   bounces={false}
   onScroll={onScroll}>
   {state.sections.map(section => (
      <Item key={section.id} category={section}
            onItemLayout={onItemLayout} data={data} />
   ))}
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
const onScroll = ({ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y, x } } }) => {
    let _currentSection;
    // loop sections to calculate which section scrollview is on
    state.sections.forEach((section, index) => {
      // adding 15 to calculate Text's height
      const moveToPosition = wp('24') * 5.8 * index
      // console.log((y), state[section], index, moveToPOsition)
      if ((y + 15) > moveToPosition) _currentSection = index
    })

    const moveTabToPosition = ((Screen.width) / 5) * _currentSection
    tabScrollView.current?.scrollTo({ x: moveTabToPosition, y: 0, animated: true });
    if (state.currentSection != _currentSection) {
      // settint the currentSection to the calculated current section
      setState((currentState) => ({ ...currentState, currentSection: _currentSection }))
    }
  }
```

and add it in Animated.Event link this

```
const handleScroll = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: { y: scrollY.current },
        },
      },
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: true,
      listener: event => {
        onScroll(event);
      },
    },
  );
```